# sql server management studio 2008

Tags: sql-server

I just created two tables using a query create statement. I'm trying to get the database to show up in object expolorer but have no idea which folder it is in. I want to view the table itself so that I can make changes to the relationships. Right now I can only see that the database and the tables were created successfully but am having a hard time finding the table itself.

Answer (score 0):

What database did you create them in? They will be under that database node.

Note that you will need to refresh the list before you can see the new tables - right click the `tables` node and select `Refresh`.

Answer (score 0):

Try refrshing the tables node of the database.  Right click and choose refresh on Tables and choose refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Check the table name in the dropdown on the top left, sometimes it goes to master database by default, so you might have accidentally created them on master database (if you have not used `"use YourDatabaseName"` statement before your create statements)